# NHibernate Join Filter (With clause?)

Tags: nhibernate, join

I am trying to figure out a way with HQL to do a "filter" on the joined object. Exmaple:

```
from Cat as cat
    inner join tableX as x
    left join tableY as y
        with x.someID = y.someID
```

I know that the "**with**" clause works fine with parameters :param like this:

```
from Cat as cat
    inner join tableX as x
    left join tableY as y
        with x.someID = :param
```

But in my case I do not have a parameter.

### Update:

Here is a little bit more info:

```
Table Cat       TableX:              TableY:
---------       ------               --------
PK ID           PK EntityID          PK EntityID
Column 1        Column State         Column State     
Column 2        Column 1             Column 1
Column 3        Column 2
```

Table Cat and Table Y are with one-to-one mapping.
Table Cat and Table X are with one-to-many mapping.

I basically want to say in HQL:

```
SQL:    SELECT *
        FROM Cat c
        INNER JOIN TableX x on c.ID = x.EntityID
        LEFT JOIN TableY y on x.EntityID = y.EntityID and x.State = y.State
```

Any ideas for this or ways around it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does your first query not work?

Comment: No, only the second works, it does not allow me to put table aliases in the WITH clause, only parameters :(

Comment: Sorry the original title confused me. Is there a reason you can't just use a where clause?

Comment: In this case the result set is quite different if I put the x.someID=y.someID in the where due to the left join. I need to use a left join specifically. 

I will try to update the example above with more info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve is not possible without a mapping association. You can't do an outer theta join, only cross and inner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vadim... How would you do the mapping in this case to get NHibernate to add the "AND" in the left outer join? I am looking at this issue for some time now and I do not see a mapping to give me this either ... your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Akrion, I don't really know your domain. You could have a `<many-to-one>` association between the 2 entities. That said, don't be afraid to use good old fashion SQL if it doesn't make sense in your domain for the 2 entities to know about each other and if you need a very specific query that cannot be accomplished in HQL. You can return entities from a SQL query. [link](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e10207)

Comment: The problem with the good old SQL is that the code relies on the HQL IQuery ReturnAliases method to get the column aliases, but if you use a <sql-query> NHibernate does not provide any information about the returned result set as far as I can see ... None of the collections are populated ... no ReturnAliases, no ReturnTypes etc.

Comment: @Akrion, I don't mean using a named sql query, although you could. Read the link again about adding root entities and joins to a sql query.